# Recursively unpacking a template pack for a parameter-less function

Tags: c++14, parameter-pack

I'm trying to create a struct template with a variadic template type pack, that can deduct the sum of the size of all types passed in.

Below you find a simplified example, in the real-world context, the size computed is used to create further member objects.

```
template <typename... Types>
struct OverallSize
{
    template <typename FirstType, typename... NextTypes>
    static constexpr size_t sizesum() { return sizeof (FirstType) + sizesum<NextTypes...>(); }
    template <typename LastType>
    static constexpr size_t sizesum() { return sizeof (LastType); }

    static constexpr size_t size = sizesum<Types...>();
};

// Should work e.g. like this
auto s = OverallSize<int, float, char>::size; // s will be 9 on x86-64
```

I'm used to this recursive parameter unpacking approach when it comes to argument lists and assumed this works as well with argument-less functions and explicit template specification. However I get the following error when compiling with clang

```
Call to 'sizesum' is ambiguous
...
Candidate function [with FirstType = unsigned long, NextTypes = <>]
Candidate function [with LastType = unsigned long]
```

So it seems as if the last recursion iteration doesn't work here – not sure why the compiler doesn't simply chose the most obvious choice: The one with only one template type – just as it would happen if there was an actual template argument passed to the function.

So, what do I have to do to make this compile and work as desired?

Comment: With fold expression (c++17) it can be reduced to : `static constexpr size_t size = (sizeof(Types) + ...);`.

Comment: Sadly the highest standard supported in the corresponding project is c++14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C++14 you can use SFINAE:

```
template <
    typename FirstType, 
    typename... NextTypes, 
    std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(NextTypes) >= 1>* = nullptr >
static constexpr size_t sizesum() {
    return sizeof (FirstType) + sizesum<NextTypes...>(); 
}
```

this template will be considered only if parameters pack has size >= 1.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cc7U2k)

Comment: Great! The power (and horrible readable syntax at the same time) of SFINAE expressions surprises me again and again